# How to drag/re-position inspect element tool in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-inspector

I am using Google Chrome browser. I did right click -> inspect element to open up the inspect element tool. This is what I currently see on my screen

[image]

Is there a way I can re-position/move the inspect element tool to the bottom of the browser screen? 
I tried looking this up https://www.google.com/#q=drag+and+drop+inspect+element but only found results for shortcuts to open the inspect element tool.

Comment: Thanks to your question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be able to click and hold the little "two squares" icon next to the "close" icon, and it will reveal an option to move the DevTools to the bottom:

[image: screenshot]

The half-filled rectangle will move the DevTools to the side/bottom, and the overlapping squares will pop the DevTools out of your browser into a separate window.

Comment: This is now obsolete

Comment: @JGallardo click the three dots and the option is in the drop down

Answer (score 17):

My answer is based on Chrome 59 but currently applies to previous versions since then.

As shown in image, you can click the 3 vertical dots on top right, then the menu below will appear, there you can click on your preferred arrangement (the darkened box portion shows where you would like to put the toolbar). In your case select the icon which has the bottom arrangement.

[image: Move Doc to bottom in Chrome 59]

Answer (score 1):

Just before the close icon in inspect element  , there is docking icon.
If the docking  is like single box icon, just click on it to toggle the inspect element between bottom and  right.
If the docking icon is like double box icon , press the icon ,hold it and then move the cursor to the single box icon(which appears shortly after pressing the icon).
For more information visit [here](http://gomedia.com/zine/tutorials/quick-tips-google-chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: What additional information does this add to an already answered question?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are a keyboard shortcut guy,

- If you are in windows
  <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- In OSX
  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Windows PC 2020 version

`Toogle Device toolbar` select or deselect

[image]

Comment: That changes the view of the screen (e.g. to an iPad), but not the location of the inspect element